# Node.js simplest code not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

As I am a newbie to Node.js and is learning from different articles. So, far I have learnt, my code is

At server side with ***app.js***

```
var http = require('http');

var app = http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
    req.on('end',function()
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello');
    });
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket)
{
    socket.emit('connect',{msg:'Hello Client'});
    socket.on('client_Says',console.log);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

At client side with ***index.html***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('//localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect',function(data)
{
    alert('Server says '+data.msg);
    socket.emit('client_Says',{data:'Hello Server'});
});
</script>
```

What is that I am doing wrong in above code? When I run app.js in console, it says **info - socket.io started** but when I run *http://localhost:3000* it just keep requesting server.

plus I want to know that is it true that wherever on my pc I create my folder for Node and place **app.js** and **index.html** files like above in it and run *http://localhost:3000* in browser will automatically make that folder my site folder for localhost after running app.js in Node console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.js update code to this

```
 var http = require('http'),
     fs = require('fs'), //<--- File Module
     index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');

 var app = http.createServer(function(req,res)
 {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //<-Updated to text/html
      res.end(index); //<---I am sending page
 });
```

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: Now browser opens page and writes **Hello** but no alert is shown as I have coded in index.html

Comment: Then you should update your code and send index.html while server is created. Look for my code I have update. Suggested in http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do this on server side:

```
socket.emit('connect',{msg:'Hello Client'});
```

because `connect` is a default event which is emitted on a successful connection from the server. So when a client connects, the server fires its default 'connect' event, but here you're also triggering your event named connect which might be causing problem.

Comment: Thanks @M Omary. I didn't knew this